# Put content in a div

Tags: jquery

If I already have like

```
<div class="key-element"></div>
<div class="key-element"></div>
<div class="key-element"></div>
<div class="key-element"></div>
<div class="key-element"></div>
<div class="key-element"></div>
```

Is it possible to give one of these element a value? Do I need to give every div some sort of unique value in order to process this?

Comment: Which element among those you want to put value to?

Comment: What do you mean by "give it a value"?

Comment: I'm not shure if I undertood you correctly: So you want to insert content in a specific `div`, for example into the 3rd `div`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector. For example if you wanted to change the html of the fourth div:

```
$('.key-element:eq(3)').html('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in Javascript/JQuery?

If so then your best bet is to give each Div an id which can be fetched by the scripting language.

If you don't want to do that, and they are the only Divs or they are in a container you can do a foreach loop and store them in an Array.

Lastly you could use the eq selector http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_eq.asp (Edit: As mentioned above)

It really depends what your trying to do.

Comment: w3schools? seriously? I won't downvote your answer for referencing this site but there might be other people that will.

Comment: Whats wrong with W3Schools? Its just a link to learn more about the selector.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ would have been more appropriate than W3Schools here.... I don't like downvoting :)

Comment: @LexEichner, see here what's wrong: http://w3fools.com/. And please don't put links to this site on Stack Overflow anymore.

Comment: Fair enough. It was just meant as a reference, not for a full blown tutorial. Will keep that in mind though :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanted to change the html of the fourth div using javascript:**

```
function setContent(content){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("key-element");
    for(var i=0 ; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs.innerHTML = content;
    }
}

setContent("Hello");
```

Comment: This question is tagged with jQuery, so I suspect he wants a solution via jQuery.